# How are Express middleware chained?

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following in app.js

```
var app = require("express")();

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(require("./routes/admin");
...
```

And in ./routes/admin.js:

```
var router = require("express").Router();

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
router.use(bodyParser.json());

router.get("/", (req, res)=> { res.send("test"); });
...

module.exports = router;
```

The main `app` already has `bodyParser` as a middleware, and app uses `admin` as a route. Is the `router.use(bodyParser.json())` statement required in admin.js if I want to use it in admin.js? Would a request be parsed in app.js before continuing to admin.js?

Comment: You only need to register middleware once. Think of it like an "onion" where requests come "in" and go through each layer of the onion until the core, and then the same on the way "out" passing through each layer until the edge. Hence "middleware", as being what sits in the "middle" of the conversations of the server. That sort of terminology and implementation is the same on every platform you find that uses the term "middleware" as to how it is applied and how it is used.

Comment: I could imagine middleware that would be useful to require several times. But in this case second bodyParser just do nothing